# Issue with extra character in MD5 Hash?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, md5

I've got a login script that I'm just starting on.  When a new password is entered it is first encrypted using MD5, then stored in the database.

When I type the username and password in my login form and submit it, I'm trying to verify the stored password against a $_POST variable like this:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
//database stuff here
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q))
{
    if ($row['password'] == $password)
    {
        echo "Passwords match.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Password is incorrect.";
        echo "<br />Entered password: " . $password;
        echo "<br />Stored password: " . $row['password'];
    }
}
```

This is just in the testing stages, so the password that I'm attempting to verify is 'password', for simplicity.  If I output $_POST['password'], I get password - however, if I output the MD5 hash as stored in the database and md5($_POST['password']), they do not match.  The latter has extra characters.  Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: 1. MD5 is a very weak algorithm, use something from SHA-2 family, eg. SHA-256. 2. Salt your passwords. 3. Use PDO and prepared statements for database connectivity.

Comment: @Crozin: while you are at it, better propose bcrypt or PBKDF2 with a high iteration count and salt per password instead of just a hash and salt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the other answers, MD5 as an algorithm does not produce hexadecimal characters at all. MD5 is an operation that is performed on binary data. As output, it returns 16 bytes of binary data.

It's the PHP function that returns a hexadecimal string. It depends on the way you want to handle the output of the hash if this is what you want. If you store the hash as binary data you might want to use the "raw" output:

`string md5 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )`

Answer (score 4):

Your column type could be truncating the data when you store it.

Check that it is at least 32 characters (the size of an MD5 hash).

Also, this script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I realize this script is vulnerable - it's a fledgling trial.  Right now it's localhost only, it'll be beefed up before going live = )

Answer (score 2):

Your field is too short. MD5 hashes have 32 hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get tricked. Check this:

```
$str=md5('password');
print(strlen($str));
```

and the output is 32. (the string is "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99")

Now try inserting this within html code:

```
<?=print(md5('password'));?>
```

And the output is "5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf991" (33 chars)

The issue gets clearer when you insert:

```
<?=print(strlen(md5('password')));?>
```

The output is "321"

This works:

```
<?php print(strlen(md5('password')));?>
```